# Any way to add dependency to lein project without REPL restart?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

What I do now is open project.clj, add dependency there, run `lein deps` restart repl, then `use`, `require` and so on.

The thing is that I don't really like to restart repl because the startup time is slow and I have to reload my files again.

So is there a better way to add dependency to lein project? without restarting the repl?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [Alembic](https://github.com/pallet/alembic), a dynamic classpath loader and dependencies resolver. The good thing is that it doesn't load all pomegranate dependencies.

Add the following to your `.lein/profiles.clj`:

```
{:user
  {:dependencies [[alembic "0.3.2"]]}}
```

Then in your Repl just load the classpaths you need, they will be pulled from the repositories by `lein`if need:

```
(require 'alembic.still)
(alembic.still/distill '[enlive "1.1.5"])
```

`(require 'net.cgrand.enlive-html)` should now work.

Comment: Oh wow, missed this while writing essentially the same answer. +1.

Comment: @Kolja, Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 13):

for quick testing you can use [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) to add dependencies on the fly

```
=> (use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies)])
nil
=> (add-dependencies :coordinates '[[incanter "1.2.3"]])
```

for actually adding a dependency I ususally hit

- <kbd>Alt-x</kbd> nrepl-restart
- <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>ctrl-k</kbd> to reload the file,
- <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>alt-n</kbd> to get back to the namespace i in the buffer

The whole process takes the jvm startup time (which i agree is a touch painful) plus five seconds. It helps to keep your project in a state where loading a file does all the require initialization.